# What's the meaning of the phrase "take cares of"?

Tags: meaning

What is the usage, and why use plural?

The context is here:

> The automatic support for long -
>   running workfl ows that the WF
>   infrastructure provides is the most
>   evident benefi t. The execution of a
>   long - running workfl ow can be
>   suspended or resumed on multiple
>   points, so the internal state of the
>   execution and activities must be
>   preserved. WF automatically **takes
>   cares of** saving the workfl ow state
>   through the use of confi gurable
>   providers. Therefore, you do not need
>   to worry about these details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It's not a word, it's a fragment.
2. Please give an example of its being used.
3. I can't think of a realistic example where *take cares of* wouldn't be grammatically incorrect.

Update on your example: Your example is grammatically incorrect, so I guess it's a typo.  The phrase should be 'takes care of', and it means 'deals with' or 'handles'.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I modified it my question and provided the context, I am wondering it might be a typo of the author. I am Chinese and not very good at English, I want to confirm it!

Comment: In addition, this would have passed a spell-checker, since both words are spelled correctly. Which is probably why no one ever noticed this error.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is "takes care of" and there is no plural involved. *Takes* is the 3rd person singular form of the verb, as in

> John takes care of someone on the weekends, so he won't be available then.

Comment: I encountered it in a book, maybe a typo of the author.I want to confirm it. Thanks for your answering!